# React Native Radio button with multiple props

Tags: react-native, properties, radio-button, radio-group

I am trying to pass a 3rd variable/prop through to my onselect so that I can display the name of the element which has been selected along with the value, and index. the problem is I keep getting undefined for desc

```
_onSelect (index, value, desc) {
    console.log(`Item: ${desc}, index: ${index} , value: ${value}`)
    this.cartFirebase.update(
      {
        index: index,
        price: value
      }
    )
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <RadioGroup
        onSelect={(index, value, desc) => this._onSelect(index, value, desc)}
        color='#009688'
        highlightColor='#fff'
      >
        {(this.props.item || []).map((section, i) => (
          <RadioButton value={section.price} desc={section.description} key={i} style={styles.row}>
            <Text style={styles.title}>{section.description}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.price}>{Settings.priceToPriceWithCurrency(section.price)}</Text>
          </RadioButton>
        ))}
      </RadioGroup>
    )
  }
}
```